# Converting string into int in php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a BMI calculator and the imperial system works perfectly in my code. However in the metric system I can't do the math because php thinks my variable is a string, retrieving "Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in...".

I've already tried intval(), (int)$var, $var += 0, etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```html
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $check = $_POST['toggleUnits'];
  if ($check == "Metric") {

   $height=$_POST['height'];
   $weight=$_POST['weight'];
   $height = $height/100;
   $bmi = round($weight / ($height * $height), 1);

  }
  else {

   $heightFt=$_POST['heightft'];
   $heightIn=$_POST['heightin'];
   $weight=$_POST['weight'];
   $height = ($heightFt * 12) + $heightIn;
   $bmi = round(($weight * 703)/($height * $height), 1);

  }
    
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the POST data not contains any value different of `.` or `1234567890` ? These caracteres maybe be a valid number `int` or `float`

Comment: @kip there is a form that is getting the value from and, when I press submit,  this is what var_dump retrieves: string(0) "" float(1243.32), even though I entered integers.

Comment: The problem must be with the form then.